# nginx, Unicorn, Rails, Postgres and database parallelism when requests take a long time to finish?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nginx

Using a nginx, Unicorn, Rails, Postgres deployment in a semi-production environment. In the same app I have two users requesting some information and one of the requests takes around 10s. During this time the other user has to sit there as requesting any URL seems to stall.

How can this be addressed?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an app-server behind your nginx (Using nginx as load-balancer and/or reverse proxy), that has multiple processes and clustering support.

> Without multiple processes, your app is bottlenecked by Ruby code execution as only one process thread can run Ruby code at a time. Without multithreading, your app may be prematurely bottlenecked by slow I/O.

You should look into Puma, Unicorn and Passenger, and determine which one i right for you. I'm used both Puma and Unicorn, in different setups, and I'm quite fond of both in each their own way.

In general, if you use Puma, Unicorn or Passenger behind nginx, you'll be able to handle multiple request in parallel.

There are a number of articles on this matter, that I have found some of here:

- http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/02/10/which-ruby-app-server-is-right-for-you
- https://blog.codeship.com/puma-vs-unicorn/

Comment: I already have Unicorn behind nginx, hmm i think I probably configured it wrong, followed some basic tutorial on then web to get it running. What do I have to look for?

Comment: You're looking for unicorn workers count, to increase throughput. -
 See `worker_processes` setting https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-unicorn-workers-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app